# ADO.net DataReader is called recursivley -> does not start again at the beginning in new recursive frame

Tags: c#, recursion, ado.net, oledbdatareader

please imagine this method prototype:

```
protected void getChildren(int parentIdeaIdentifier, OleDbDataReader reader, ref string result, int level)
```

Call is e.g. getChildren(331, reader, "empty", 0);

Assume the reader (OleDbDataReader) has these simplified 4 entries:

```
[0]: reader["Idea_ID"]: "148"
[1]: reader["Idea_ID"]: "72"
[2]: reader["Idea_ID"]: "331"
[3]: reader["Idea_ID"]: "331"
```

So now please have a look at this small recursive method:

```
protected void getChildren(int parentIdeaIdentifier, OleDbDataReader reader, ref string parentAndChildren, int level)
    {
            while (reader.Read())   //4 times in our case
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(reader["Parent_Idea_Identifier"].ToString()) == parentIdeaIdentifier)
                {
                    ideaIdentifier = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Idea_Identifier"].ToString());
                     //parentAndChildren = "do something";
                      getChildren(ideaIdentifier, reader, ref parentAndChildren, level - 1);

                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
    }
```

It is NOT important, that you understand what this method does!
But here comes the problem:

The while-loops in total 4 times if function is entered the first time.
Operation is ONLY done e.g. if reader is 331!
If it is 331 this function is called again recursively with different parameters.

***Problem:***
This DataReader does not start again from index [0] but somehow remembers its state. So if I get into this function again in the 2nd level reader starts from where it ended, in this case from index[2].

How can I make the DataReader start from the beginning again?
Is dataReader the wrong datastructure for that?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: DataReaders are "forward only" and cannot go back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, wrong structure.

Use a data adapter to fill a DataTable and use that DataTable instead of your DataReader.

Or as stuartd pointed out, you can create the DataTable from your reader:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader);
```

So instead of a while loop, you would use a foreach on the Rows collection.

Comment: DataTable has [a Load method which will populate straight from the reader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x8ccbsb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)